# Which game is this 2D character sprite in a battle stance from?

Tags: game-identification

[image: 2D character in battle stance]

She looks like she's from a Capcom fighting game, but the level of detail made me wonder which system. It looks too 2d for anything past the PSX/Saturn/Dreamcast era. Am I right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

She's Vice, capcomesque version.
http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Vice

Comment: The sprite is from a Capcom title. Capcom vs. SNK / Pro / 2

Answer (score 8):

[Adrian is right](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13445/which-game-is-this-character-from/13449#13449): It's Vice from King of Fighters ([link](http://kofaniv.snkplaymore.co.jp/english/character/index.php?num=vice))

King of Fighters was originally neogeo, though they've actually done a few crossovers with more conventional capcom games. It holds a special place in my heart for being the only fighting game series that I was actually *really* good at.

One of my fondest arcade memories was walking into an arcade that had just had a brand new KoF v Capcom machine delivered, and completely pwning all these kids who'd never even *seen* a neogeo. Played 5 games without losing a single round, got a buzz on my (at the time sexy and modern) pager, passed my game to some kid, and walked out a legend.

Comment: That's cool. So...is this character sprite from a KoF game, then?

Comment: @Mana Vice is originally from KoF though I can't say whether this particular sprite is. Satanic, while a nice story, this doesn't actually answer the question, so you might consider either making this a comment or at least providing a direct answer inside the text body.

Comment: @grace: Adrian answered it perfectly well. I was just following up with more detailed console information.

Comment: If you want to follow up, use a comment or at least reference the answer you're following up (ideally by link). When doing a followup, context is important to prevent readers from getting lost; there's no guarantee that a reader will see Adrian's answer before yours.

Comment: @Grace, that is, unless Adrian's answer gets accepted, pinning it to the top of the answers, which is something @ixtmixilix should do.